# Pegar link do compartilhamento

Tags: javascript, facebook

Quero compartilhar uma postagem no Facebook resgatando o link do compartilhamento, para que consiga compartilhar este link no Twitter. Estou dando uma olhada na documentação do Facebook, acredito que permita isso de alguma forma simples.

Comment: Você está usando a JavaScript SDK do Facebook? Todo post que você fizer com ela terá como retorno o ID da publicação. Com este ID você pode montar a URL final ou fazer uma requisição na API e pegar todos os dados.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12692/2554

Answer (score 3):

Você quer compartilhar o link do facebook?

Por que não usa o mesmo link que usou para o facebook em outras redes sociais?

Explica melhor, por favor.

Se você estiver usando PHP, veja uma função para compartilhar em todas as redes sociais interagindo com o click do usuário.

```
<?php
function social_networks ($title, $link) {
    $FB = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' . rawurlencode($link) . '&t=' . rawurlencode($title);
    $google_plus = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url=' . rawurlencode($link) .'';

    $twitter = "window.open('http://twitter.com/home?status=". rawurlencode($title) ."','popups','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=700,height=500,top=100,left=100'); return false;";

    $facebook = "window.open('$FB','popups','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=700,height=500,top=100,left=100'); return false;";

    $gplus = "window.open('$google_plus','popups','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=700,height=500,top=100,left=100'); return false;";

    return (object) array( 'twitter' => $twitter, 'facebook' => $facebook, 'gplus' => $gplus );
}

$share = social_networks('Título', 'LINK');
?>
<!-- HTML -->
<a href="#" onclick="<?php echo $share->facebook ?>">Compartilhar no facebook</a>
<a href="#" onclick="<?php echo $share->twitter ?>">Compartilhar no Twitter</a>
<a href="#" onclick="<?php echo $share->gplus ?>">Compartilhar no Google plus</a>
```

**E com javascript:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var social_networks = function(title, link) {
    var FB = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent(link) + '&t='+ encodeURIComponent(title);
    var google_plus = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url=' + encodeURIComponent(link);

    var twitter = "window.open('http://twitter.com/home?status="+encodeURIComponent(title)+"','popups','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=700,height=500,top=100,left=100'); return false;";

    var facebook = "window.open('"+ FB +"','popups','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=700,height=500,top=100,left=100'); return false;";

    var gplus = "window.open('"+ google_plus +"','popups','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=700,height=500,top=100,left=100'); return false;";

    return {'twitter':twitter, 'facebook':facebook, 'gplus':gplus};
};

var share = social_networks('Título', 'LINK');

// $(document).ready [...]
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('facebook').setAttribute('onclick', share.facebook);
    document.getElementById('twitter').setAttribute('onclick', share.twitter);
    document.getElementById('gplus').setAttribute('onclick', share.gplus);
};
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" id="facebook">Compartilhar no facebook</a>
    <a href="#" id="twitter">Compartilhar no Twitter</a>
    <a href="#" id="gplus">Compartilhar no Google plus</a>
</body>
</html>
```