# Como criar um app no Facebook para compartilhar postagens na rede social

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Quero colocar uma opção de compartilhamento em um aplicativo meu e notei que o addThis tem um app no Facebook para esse tipo de ação mas na postagem lá no perfil da pessoa fica o ícone com um link e informações do addThis e digamos que não quero fazer "publicidade" e não fica legal para o meu app, sei lá, eu acho.

Já procurei tutorial no Google e não achei, até tentei fazer sozinho lá no Facebook Developer mas não descobri como (é muito complicado lá '-').

Eu já tenho o app, só quero saber como faço o método de compartilhar as postagens e se não me engano acho que dá para colocar uma frase na caixa onde o usuário vai digitar alguma coisa, que ficaria mais ou menos assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Google+ tem uma api para compartilhar postagens dentro da página mesmo usando Javascript, o Facebook também tem isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A melhor - e mais correta - forma de fazer isso é usando a SDK JavaScript do Facebook.
Dê uma olhada na [documentação](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart) antes de começar que vale muito a pena. É bem didática.

**Iniciando a JS SDK**

- Crie uma div #fb-root
- Inclua o JavaScript do Facebook
- Substitua {your-app-id} pelo ID da sua aplicação

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{your-app-id}',
      status     : true,
      xfbml      : true
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

**Compartilhar**

```
function share() {
FB.ui(
  {
   method: 'feed', //Método para postar no Mural
   name: 'Título do conteúdo',
   caption: 'Linha abaixo do conteúdo. Não obrigatório.',
   description: 'Descrição. Recomendado no máximo 255 caracteres.',
   link: 'http://google.com/', //Link a ser compartilhado
   picture: 'http://google.com/logo.png' //Imagem do Share
  },
  function(response) {
     console.log(response); //Callback da função.
  }
);
}
</script>
```

Documentação JavaScript: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript

Feed e Dialogs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog

Comment: Eu fiz do jeito que você falou mas aparece esse erro: API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
Eu mudei o valor de "link". Tem algum problema se a img for de outro site?

Comment: @IagoBruno Provavelmente a URL que você está compartilhando não está autorizada no seu aplicativos. Acesse o seu aplicativo em Developers e vá na aba Settings. Lá, clique em Add Platform e selecione Website. Configure a URL do seu site e pronto. Agora adicione o seu domínio em App Domains. Provavelmente isso resolverá.

Comment: Deu certo o/ mas só uma coisa, note que nessa img (http://i.stack.imgur.com/uRxwX.jpg) tem uma mensagem pre escrita que é definida por mim, tem como fazer isso?

Comment: @IagoBruno se não me engano é a propriedade "message" no FB.ui

Comment: Não deu certo =/

Comment: ah, cabei de ler aqui que essa função foi desativado da api =/. Como dúvida final, queria saber como faz para compartilhar direto na page (assim: http://i.stack.imgur.com/J1CjO.png (ignore o quadrado vermelho))

Comment: @IagoBruno como assim?

Comment: Esse box está em um iframe dentro da página.

Comment: @IagoBruno você pode adicionar a função de Share no parent(janela principal) e chamar a função JavaScript do parent pelo iFrame. //parent.share();